# XML and C# - Help pulling information from a certain element

Tags: c#, xml

So I don't know how to exactly word it, but here it goes. Right now my Application can pull the information about the User's from the XML without problem. Sample XML:

```
<statuses type="array">
<status>
  <id>ID1</id>
  <text>Text That I want to pull 1</text>
  <user>
    <name>User1</name>
    <screen_name>User1_Screen</screen_name>
    <location>Location_User1</location>
    <Description>User1_Description</Description>
  </user>
</status>
<status>
  <id>ID2</id>
  <text>Text That I want to pull 2</text>
  <user>
    <name>User2</name>
    <screen_name>User2_Screen</screen_name>
    <location>Location_User2</location>
    <Description>User2_Description</Description>
  </user>
</status>
```

Which the Screen_name tag gets pulled into a listbox. And here's the code that pulls the information in which it gets user's detail's:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load the temp file
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Temp.xml");


        var setting = doc.Descendants("user").First(a => a.Element("screen_name").Value == listBox1.Text);

        //Variables for information from XML
        var Location = setting.Element("location").Value;
        var Description = setting.Element("description").Value;
        var Screen_name = setting.Element("name").Value;

        //Info Pulled from "temp.xml"
        location.Text = "Location: "+Location;
        Username.Text = "Name: " + Screen_name;
        descriptionBox.Text = "Description: "+Description;
    }
```

and All i want now is the text tag also, and I'm just having a terrible time figuring it out.

Comment: @hamish: Not overusing it at all. var is _not_ dynamic so the code is statically typed.
var Location = setting.Element("location").Value; 
and
string Location = setting.Element("location").Value; are sematically equal

Comment: @Hamish: var is statically typed, just anonymous (no name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code without any problems. You should to check:

- Is your `listBox1.Text` value correct?
- Are you trying to acess that `Temp.xml` in correct path?
- Are you sure your `Temp.xml` is well-formed (it's missing a `</statuses>`); Try to open it into your IE.

**EDIT**: Try this:

```
var text = setting.Parent.Element("text").Value;
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I posed my Question wrong, I also want to pull the text tag, but I cant seem to pull it right with what I'm working with.